# Referencing SQL results from a PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, class, variables

I am use ezsql to access my Mysql db, which is working great.  $db->get_results() gives me the results in the form of a class, so I reference fields like $user->name, $user->email, etc.

I am trying to automate a few things and would like to use a function to reference the specific values by variable like an array, but can't seem to grasp how to do this.  For example:

```
function getVal($field){
return $user->$field;
}
```

Then call the function like: `getVal("name")` or`getVal("email");`

Is this even possible?  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted, the $user variable is not set inside the function -- you have to pass it as a parameter :

```
function getVal($user, $field){
    return $user->$field;
}
```

But I don't really see why you would do that...

*(Kind of a wild guess)*

If that function is actually a method inside some kind of `User` class, which contains the data, you should use `$this` to access the properties :

```
function getVal($user, $field){
    return $this->$field;
}
```

Comment: I see that I wasn't thinking clearly.  The function isn't inside a class, but probably should be. Thanks for the quick clarification, I'm off to write better code.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt make any sense.. why would you replace the object accessor with a function call unless its a method on the actual class for `$user`?

That said you need to pass in the user to the function:

```
function getVal($field, $result)
{
  return $result->$field;
}
```

but the better thing to do would be to implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) on the Result class since this is what you are trying to to do. This way you can use `$user['name']` just the same as `$user->name` or to add a public `get` method to the result class:

```
public function get($field)
{
  return $this->$field;
}
```

Not that you can use variables to access properties which makes what you are trying to do even more strange to me:

```
// you can always do the following
$field = 'name';
echo $user->$field;
```